# PAE in x86-64 bit processors - Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, operating-system, x86-64, paging

I have noticed that the PAE bit in the CR4 register is turned on my Linux (3.19) x86-64 machine. The PAE feature allows physical addresses up to 64gb to be accessed but I do not understand why it is needed when long-mode is enabled. I have looked it up for a while but haven't found any satisfying answer.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is using IA-32e paging.

> A logical processor uses IA-32e paging if *CR0.PG* = 1, **CR4.PAE** = 1, and *IA32_EFER.LME* = 1.
>   With IA-32e paging, linear address are translated using a hierarchy of in-memory paging structures located using the contents of *CR3*.
>   IA-32e paging translates 48-bit linear addresses to 52-bit physical addresses.
>   Although 52 bits corresponds to 4 PBytes, linear addresses are limited to 48 bits; at most 256 TBytes of linear-address space may be accessed at any
>   given time.

---

x86 processors supports three paging modes:

1. 32-bit paging (*CR0.PG* = 1 and *CR4.PAE* = 0)
2. PAE paging (*CR0.PG* = 1, *CR4.PAE* = 1, and *IA32_EFER.LME* = 0)
3. IA-32e paging (*CR0.PG* = 1, *CR4.PAE* = 1, and *IA32_EFER.LME* = 1)

A table summarising the differences is reported here (as image, unfortunately)

[image: Differences between the three paging modes on x86]